# i need migrate after laravel teelscope

Tags: laravel

I removed a composer package, with composer remove laravel/telescope But getting to the end of the command output I got

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Can you clear cache from laravel and composer.

Comment: can u say me the detail of that u order thank u

Comment: bcs   i  try all of same that

Comment: ```php artisan cache:clear``` and ```composer clear-cache```

Comment: php artisan clear:cache

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider' not found

Comment: i am waiting     Clearing cache (cache-vcs-dir): C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Composer\vcs

Comment: Looking an answer from A.A Noman, i think you need follow him instruction.

Comment: Clearing cache (cache-vcs-dir): C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Composer\vcs
Clearing cache (cache-repo-dir): C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Composer\repo
Clearing cache (cache-files-dir): C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Composer\files
Clearing cache (cache-dir): C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Composer
All caches cleared.  but after this  i got that eror again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212157/discussion-between-ehsan-and-gary-houbre).

Answer (score 3):

Remove all the `telescope` reference in your code before running `composer remove laravel/telescope`.

Check first `config/app.php`, under `providers` array, remove the `Telescope` there

And where you install `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` is there a `TelescopeServiceProvider or your_provider` there? Remove that also.

If exit `bootstrap/cache/config.php` was still a line 'App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider', removed it.

You can run `composer remove laravel/telescope`.

Then finally run command `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: //App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class,

i have done yr first recommendation 

but i cant found any 

TelescopeServiceProvider or your_provider
=>>>>in here  !
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider


 but i only have   .gitignore    and packages.php  andservices.php    in bootstrap

so  i am going to   do   your final advise

Comment: Thanks   i have done    thats worked     Discovered Package: tcg/voyager
Package manifest generated successfully.

C:\Users\Ehsan\Desktop\NewAlbum\Albms77>php artisan cache:clear
Application cache cleared!

Comment: Welcome @Ehsan. If you think it is helpful for you please selected as accept for future users who will face this problem.